# code for transliterateration from Tamil(Indian language) to english

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to do the transliteration of Tamil(Indian Language) to English.

e.g.

Tamil Word

பஞ்சவர்ணம்

I want transliterate to English like "Pancavarnam"

Please help me with  code sample .

Comment: Do you need translation (Darin's answer +1) or basic transliteration (convert each "letter" in one alphabet to one-or-more characters in anoter without paying attention to a meaning)?

Comment: @ alexei-yes u r right i want to do transliteration could you please help me on that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an online translation service such as [`Google Translate API`](https://developers.google.com/translate/) or [`Microsoft Translator`](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/) which could perform this translation at runtime. But if you want a reliable translation you'd better do that translation yourself in a RESX file. Of course that's only possible if the data you are trying to translate is not dynamic.

Comment: For Microsoft Translate API, it's in the documentation: http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/ They offer AJAX, SOAP and pure HTTP interface for their API. For Google, the API is described here: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest All you have to do is to send a simple HTTP request to the described endpoint to get the translated text as response.

Comment: Side note: Google Translate API is a paid service.

Comment: @xeondev, Microsoft Translate API is also a paid service. Actually there's a free version you could use which is limited to a certain amount of translations per month.

Comment: Hi Darin,Thanks for the quick reply. could you Please give me  any sample code to that.

Comment: @vishal, which service would you like to get a sample for?

Comment: @Darin - I mean any sample code by which i can do the transliteration.

Comment: @vishal, did you read my answer in which I exposed a couple of possible solutions involving using the Google and Microsoft translation API? Which one of the two services would you like to see a sample code for?